# how to use java script validation in after using the clone function

Tags: javascript

how can do separate validation in each row in java script i used in clone for add more function but i can't do validation for every row.how is this ?

help me

```js
var i = 0;
function cloneRow() {

    var row = document.getElementById("clone");
    var table = document.getElementById("data");
    var selectIndex = 1;

    var clone = row.cloneNode(true);

    table.appendChild(clone);
    clone.setAttribute("style", "");

   



}

function deleteRow(btn) {
    var result = confirm("Do you Want to delete this ?");
    if (result) {
        var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    }

}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary default btn-xs" onclick="cloneRow()" >add more...</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><br><br>

                <div class="row" id ="close">
                    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                    <div class='col-sm-4'>
                        <Form id="NAME_VALUE" method="POST" >
                            <table  class="table-striped" >
                                <tbody id="data">
                                    <tr id ="clone" style="display:none;">
                                        <td>
                                            Name :<input type="text" name="INPUT_NAME" style="width:100px;" id="name" name="INPUT_NAME"> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Value :<input type="text" name="INPUT_VALUE" style="width:100px;" id="value" name="INPUT_VALUE"> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary default btn-xs" name ="delete" style="margin-left: 5px;" onclick="deleteRow(this);
                                                    return false;">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="text-align:center" ></span></button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Name :<input type="text" name="INPUT_NAME" style="width:100px;" id="name" name="INPUT_NAME"> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Value :<input type="text" name="INPUT_VALUE" style="width:100px;" id="value" name="INPUT_VALUE"> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary default btn-xs" name ="delete" style="margin-left: 5px;" onclick="deleteRow(this);
                                                    return false;">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="text-align:center" ></span></button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table><br>
                            <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary default btn-xs" style="margin-left: 5px;" onclick="submit_login();
                                    return false;"> save.</button>
                        </Form>
                    </div>


                </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready($.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function (value, element, arg) {
    return arg != value;
},
        "Value must not equal arg."));


$(function () {

    $("#NAME_VALUE").validate({
        errorClass: "validation-error-class",
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            INPUT_NAME: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 64
            },
            INPUT_VALUE: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 64
            }
        },
        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            INPUT_NAME: {
                required: "[your name ?]",
                maxlength: "[Your name cannot exceed 64 characters]"
            },
            INPUT_VALUE: {
                required: "[ value ?]",
                maxlength: "[Your password cannot exceed 64 characters]"
            }
        },
        errorElement: "div",
        wrapper: "div",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

            error.appendTo(element.parent("td"));
            error.css('color', 'red');
            error.css('text-align', 'center');
        }
    });
});

function submit_login(  )
{

    if ($("[id='name'],[id='value']").valid()) {
        alert("Successfully saved");
    }


}
```

i like to create this type of validation every row or tr so please help me..][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Zyd.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Zyd.png)

i put this one but if i write in one text field every validation gone..

Comment: You will have to initialize `validator` for cloned elements...

Comment: how ? I am starter in javascript so please help me

Comment: If you are using a library and a particular validation plugin, it will help to include tags for them.

Comment: how  can i do this ?